# is there any query profiler in cosmos db?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm a newbie at cosmos db. and i'll be glad if someone help me to find how to catch queries that are going on local emulator. the reason why i'm asking is that now query string is appended in a few steps via linq and i need to be sure that query builder returns correct query string.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it you are using the C# SDK and LINQ to query your database.

Once your LINQ query is ready you should be doing `queryable.AsDocumentQuery()` to generate a `DocumentQuery` object and the use that to do `while(documentQuery.HasMoreResults)` `documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<yourtype>()`.

If that's not the case then you are using the SDK in an non optimal way.

All you need to do to get the generated SQL query is to do a `.ToString()` on the `documentQuery` object and you gonna get the translated query back.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, thanx!

Comment: @Nick Chapas how can I see the SQL query sent to the db from my .NET client if I use `QueryDefinition` and `FeedIterator<dynamic>` for my parametrized query rather than LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the interactions between your application and Cosmos DB database, you can use [Cosmos DB Profiler](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/cosmosdbprof) tool. It shows queries that are sent to Cosmos DB and stacktrace of relevant code that generated them.

The profiler shows statistics for each operation like duration, response status code, query execution metrics etc and also [the request units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) for each request to a database what allows to optimize query costs.

It also alerts users about common pitfalls when using Cosmos DB and recommends how to resolve them.

Available reports provided by the profiler allow to analyze Cosmos DB usage by an application.

Comment: Just a note, it is not free.